# Can an algebraic variety over a field $k$ be the union of proper closed subsets $(S_i)_{i\in I}$ with $I < k$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, large-cardinals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (of characteristic zero, if it helps).

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $k$. Let $I$ be an index set such that the cardinality of $I$ is smaller than the cardinality of $k$.

For every $i$ in $I$, let $S_i$ be a proper closed subset of $X$.

> > Is is true that $X(k) \neq \cup_{i\in I} S_i(k)$?

I see this fact used quite often when $k$ is the field of complex numbers and $I$ is a countable set. But how does one prove this? I would be happy with a reference.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{C}$ this is an immediate consequence of the Baire theorem.

Comment: In your definition of algebraic variety, you are assuming that $X$ is *irreducible* (it is better to specify, since not all the textbook make this assumption).

Comment: @abx What if you don't assume the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @Robert Israel: I was answering the last lines of the post: $k=\mathbb{C}$, $I$ countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $dim X=1$ then it follows from cardinalities, and if $dimX>1$ then apply induction on dimension to $X \cap H, S_i \cap H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane such that dimensions of $X \cap H, S_i \cap H$ all drop by 1 (such $H$ exists by cardinality).  (Embed an affine open of $X$ in projective space in general.)